# Can I launch a SGX enclave without Internet?

Tags: intel, sgx, trusted-execution-environment

I'm currently trying to use intel's privacy computing technology in the medical field. I want to build some enclaves in our data center. But the data center is not connected to the internet, that makes the remote attestation process seemingly unfeasible.
If I need to build Enclave inside the data center, what is the feasible solution to get my enclave attested.  Or is it possible to generate reports and quotes without internet access?

Another question I have is whether it is possible to have an enclave pre-attested and get a proof (or certificate). After that all user requests can be made directly based on the previous proof without having to do a remote attestation every time before interacting with the enclave.